# Supermicro ipmi dcmi privileges

Tags: ipmi, supermicro, ipmitool, bmc

Recently we tried to monitor supermicro's servers power consumption.
And got this error:

```
ipmitool -I lanplus -U readonly_user -H ip_address -P password dcmi power reading -L user

DCMI request failed because: Insufficient privilege level (d4)
```

If we run it by user with **ADMIN** privileges it's working. But we would like it to work with **USER** privileges also.

Other vendors (HPE,IBM) work just fine. Here is an example from **hp gen8** server:

```
ipmitool -I lanplus -U readonly_user -H ip_address -P password dcmi power reading -L user

Instantaneous power reading:                   139 Watts
Minimum during sampling period:                136 Watts
Maximum during sampling period:                236 Watts
Average power reading over sample period:      144 Watts
IPMI timestamp:                           Thu Mar 16 06:54:45 2023
Sampling period:                          00000300 Seconds.
Power reading state is:                   activated
```

So how do we use user with "**USER**" role to read dcmi from **supermicro ipmi**?
Is there some proprietary supermicro restriction on that? Can't find any info online.